# My defined macro doesn't work

Tags: tables, macros, tabularx

I don't want to write `\end{tabularx}` at the end of each table, so I wanted to define a the following macro:

```
\newcommand\et{\endtabularx}
```

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
$n$ & $0$ &   $1$\\
\hline
$u_n$ & $2$ &  $5$\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

but this doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\et{\end{tabularx}}

\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
$n$ & $0$ &   $1$\\
\hline
$u_n$ & $2$ &  $5$\\
\hline
\et

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of obfuscating your code, consider using an editor which will autocomplete environments.

Comment: no it doesn't work. So don't do that. (my editor autocompletes).

Comment: I do not recommend to do something like this. It not only produces confusing code, but also confuses the syntax highlighting of probably all editors.

Comment: why would you ever want to do that? but specifically for `tabularx` there are strict constraints on how it may be used within macro definitions, see the `tabularx` manual page 4

Comment: I don't think using autocomplete solves this problem because I like having a clean and minimalist code. Actually using the tabular (instead of the tabularx) package solved this.

Comment: but using a start of an environment with `\begin` and ending it with no `\end` is as far from clean code as I could  imagine, it's harder to type and will mess up any chance of reasonable syntax highlighting in your editor, and completely confuse any human co workers who have to read the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you want minimize/obfuscate the code, do it completely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\tx[3]{\begin{tabularx}{#1}{#2}#3\end{tabularx}}
\begin{document}
\tx{100pt}{|X|X|X|}{\hline
$n$ & $0$ & $1$\\\hline
$u_n$ & $2$ & $5$\\\hline}
\end{document}
```